# Getting "Error: when installing web-console"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I run gem update. I got this error message

Unresolved dependency found during sorting - activesupport (>= 4.2.0) (requested by rails-dom-testing-2.0.3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this with

```
gem install -f web-console
```